# Refresh the counter badge from previous page

Tags: flutter

I want to refresh page A's counter badge whenever I complete a task on Page B. Currently, I am unable to get the counter badge to reduce when I click the back button. I am using API to fetch the number of notifications.

This is my [Page A](https://imgur.com/a/2Wm2Pq2)'s code below. This is [Page B](https://imgur.com/a/0fCT4BA). I fetch the API by calling  `tL.getBusinessOverview(buildingid);`, to update the counter badge notifications in the initState. Any idea how can I refresh Page A after coming from Page B when completed some tasks? Completing the tasks also update the API, but I am not sure how to make Page A rebuild again because when I come click back button from Page B, it doesn't build widgets again.

```
 Expanded(
     child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
          shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
             children: List.generate(items.length, (index) {
                          return Stack(
                            children: [
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                 
                                },
                                child: Card(
                                    child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                        items[index].image.toString(),
                                        height: screenHeight(context) / 5,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: FittedBox(
                                        child: Text(
                                          items[index].name.toString(),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )),
                              ),
                              index == 0
                                  ? Positioned(
                                      right: screenWidth(context) / 300,
                                      bottom: screenHeight(context) / 10.1,
                                      child: tL.businessOverview?.pendingDaily != 0 &&
                                              tL.businessOverview?.pendingDaily !=
                                                  null
                                          ? badges.Badge(
                                              badgeStyle: badges.BadgeStyle(
                                                  badgeColor: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                      165, 36, 34, 1),
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                              badgeContent: CustomText(
                                                text: tL.businessOverview!
                                                    .pendingDaily
                                                    .toString(),
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          : SizedBox())
                                  : index == 1
                                      ? Positioned(
                                          right: screenWidth(context) / 300,
                                          bottom: screenHeight(context) / 10.1,
                                          child: tL.businessOverview?.pendingWeekly != 0 &&
                                                  tL.businessOverview?.pendingDaily !=
                                                      null
                                              ? badges.Badge(
                                                  badgeStyle: badges.BadgeStyle(
                                                      badgeColor:
                                                          Color.fromRGBO(
                                                              165, 36, 34, 1),
                                                      padding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                                  badgeContent: CustomText(
                                                    text: tL.businessOverview!
                                                        .pendingWeekly
                                                        .toString(),
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : SizedBox())
                                      : index == 2
                                          ? Positioned(
                                              right: screenWidth(context) / 300,
                                              bottom:
                                                  screenHeight(context) / 10.1,
                                              child: tL.businessOverview?.pendingPeriodic != 0 &&
                                                      tL.businessOverview
                                                              ?.pendingDaily !=
                                                          null
                                                  ? badges.Badge(
                                                      badgeStyle:
                                                          badges.BadgeStyle(
                                                              badgeColor:
                                                                  Color
                                                                      .fromRGBO(
                                                                          165,
                                                                          36,
                                                                          34,
                                                                          1),
                                                              padding:
                                                                  EdgeInsets
                                                                      .all(10)),
                                                      badgeContent: CustomText(
                                                        text: tL
                                                            .businessOverview!
                                                            .pendingPeriodic
                                                            .toString(),
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  : SizedBox())
                                          : index == 3
                                              ? Positioned(
                                                  right: screenWidth(context) /
                                                      300,
                                                  bottom: screenHeight(context) /
                                                      10.1,
                                                  child: tL.businessOverview
                                                                  ?.pendingSpecials !=
                                                              0 &&
                                                          tL.businessOverview
                                                                  ?.pendingDaily !=
                                                              null
                                                      ? badges.Badge(
                                                          badgeStyle:
                                                              badges.BadgeStyle(
                                                                  badgeColor: Color
                                                                      .fromRGBO(
                                                                          165,
                                                                          36,
                                                                          34,
                                                                          1),
                                                                  padding:
                                                                      EdgeInsets
                                                                          .all(
                                                                              10)),
                                                          badgeContent:
                                                              CustomText(
                                                            text: tL
                                                                .businessOverview!
                                                                .pendingSpecials
                                                                .toString(),
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                          ),
                                                        )
                                                      : SizedBox())
                                              : SizedBox()
                            ],
                          );
                        })),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In PageA you can attach THEN callback where you push the PageB and call setState in it, so this would refresh your PageA every time you close Page B. Example:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => const PageB()
)).then((value) => setState(() {}));
```